# ssh環境での python manage.py migrateのエラー

Tags: python, django, デプロイ

sshの仮想環境で作業しています。 (sshを抜けた一番最初の環境では　migrateもmakemigrationもできている状態です。)
python 3.6.8
pip 21.3.1
virtualenvを使用しています。
postgresqlにて、roleとdetabaseもcreateしています。
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULES=microblog.settings.prod
でモジュールも指定先としてsshに接続するたびに設定しています。

学習サイトを用いたサイト作成でデプロイをしようとしています。
他のサイト検索では settings.py に全て記述していますが、settings.pyを settings という新しいフォルダを作成し、以下４つのファイルに分割している状態です。

```
dev.py
heroku.py
prod.py
common.py
```

現在詰まっているのが、環境構築の部分で migrate できないという状態です。

prod.py, common.py がデータベース設計の部分になっております。

prod.py

```
from .common import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', ]

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'gunicorn',
)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'データベース名',
        'USER': 'データベース名と同じ',
        'PASSWORD': 'データベース名と同じ',
    }
}
```

common.py

```
"""
Django settings for microblog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
print(BASE_DIR)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = シークレットなので日本語



DATABASES = {}

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'microblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,  # False -> True
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
print(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")))

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'microblog.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # mac / : windows ¥
    os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"))

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

この二つは
/opt/django/microblog/microblog0/microblog/settings/prod.py
の階層にあり、
manage.pyは、/opt/django/microblog/microblog0
の場所にある状態です。

この設定で `pip freeze` コマンドでは

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.9
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
pytz==2021.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
```

以上の設定がinstallされています。

その状態で `python3 manage.py migrate` をすると

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

というエラーが起き、一応 psycopg2-binaryがちゃんとinstallできていないからではと提案されたのですが、uninstallし、installしなおしても同じ状態で詰まっています。

もし同じような状況になったことがある方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0):

結論から言うと、python manage.py migrateは実行できましたが。なぜ行けたのかの理由がわかりません。

CentOS7を一度保存状態で切ってsshが切断されます、再度CentOS7を起動し直しました。
その後、sshで入り、仮想環境にいき

python manage.py migrateをすると

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
```

が出ており、前回のエラーとは違います。
前回は

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

そして、VScodeでModuleNotFoundErrorとなっていた部分,prod.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'gunicorn',
)
```

こちらを削除し、source treeで

```
commit

push


以下ターミナルで

git pull

sudo systemctl restart postgresql

python manage.py migrate
```

これでmigrateが実行されました。

しかし、prod.pyにgunicornの設定をしていない状態で、初めはやっており、その状態で

```
python manage.py migrateをすると

django.core.exceptions 〜〜　のエラーが起き

gunicornを足しても、
django.core.exceptions ~~ のエラーが起きたため
```

なぜ、sshを接続し直し、exportを設定した後にmigrateをすると
エラー内容が変わり、そこを修正するだけで、migrateが通ったのかの理由がわかりませんでした。